# Undefined Variable in Laravel 8 view

Tags: laravel

I just want to Pass a Variable to the views about page.

This is the controller file

```
 public function about(){
    $name ="maneth";
    return view::make('about')->with('name', $name);
}
```

This is the about page

```
@switch($name)
@case(1)
    
    @break
@case(2)
    
    @break
@default
    
 @endswitch
```

This is the web file

```
Route::get('/about',function(){
return view('about',[PagesController::class, 'about']);
});
```

The Error is **$name is undefined**

I'm Using Laravel Framework 8.75.0

and PHP 7.3.33

Comment: You do not use the controller, you just return the "about" view in your routes-file ;) Change the routes files to use the controlller like
```
Route::get('/about', [PageController::class, 'about'])->name('page.about');
```
And then you can set the name in your controller

Comment: I tried `Route::get('/about',function(){     return view('about',[PagesController::class, 'about']); });`

Comment: This is wrong style, see my comment above. You have to jump from your web.php route file to your controller into your action, define things to be done and then return the view with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using callback in router's file and there you not sent the name variable,

You can bind controller and router file using :

```
Route::get('/about', [AboutController::class, 'about']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller action is never being executed as your route definition is returning a view directly.

Change your route so that it calls your controller and action.

```
Route::get('/about', [AboutController::class, 'about']);
```

Comment: I tried this  `Route::get('/about',function(){
    return view('about',[PagesController::class, 'about']);
});` but Still Same

Comment: @ManethPathirana That's because you've not done as I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it doesn't require any real logic (database query etc.) you can do it with a closures in your route. Otherwise you have to call the controller from your route. This would look like this:

```
Route::get('/about', [AboutController::class, 'about' ])->name('about');
```

And this would be thee closures style:

```
Route::get('/about',function(){
   $name = 'Slim Shaddy';
   return view('about', ['name' => $name]);
});
```